# How does this benchmark calculation work?

Tags: postgresql, hard-drive, benchmark, dd

I am testing disk I/O performance on a server of mine, which will eventually run Postgresql.  I am following [this web site](http://www.westnet.com/~gsmith/content/postgresql/pg-disktesting.htm) to perform my benchmarks.

The benchmark consists of running `dd` and reading/writing N blocks the size of 8k (which is the size of blocks Postgresql uses).  N is to be calculated as follows:

```
N = 250,000 * gigabytes of RAM
```

So, I have 16GB of ram, which gives me 4 million blocks to read/write.  That is fine, but...

**I am unsure where the magical number of 250,000 comes from?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Corrected per Eviler_Elf:

That's for converting between blocks and GB:

```
 1 GB / 8 kB/block * 2x = 250,000 blocks
```

Comment: ok thanks but for clarification: 1 GB / 8kb/block = 125,000 blocks, but in the article, he says to use 2X the amount, which gets you to 250,000

Comment: @Eviler_Elf good catch. I should have been a little more careful writing up my answer...